# Excel writer on fly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am reading data from a SQL Server 2008 database usnig NHibernate and I am getting a list of objects. I want to create an `.xls` Excel file on the fly and give it to user.

My problem is, I cannot make any temp files or folders in the server and cannot use any blob.

Any solutions?

Comment: you could use iis and transmit ur db tables to excel file , by using
process command to declare ur db file to iis.

Comment: can you give me some more explanation to this? I am someone new to C#.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library (to easily manipulate your workbook) saving it to a memory stream. Then, long story short, send the stream via http as usual.

```
public byte[] GetExcelByteStream(string filename)
{
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(filename))
    {
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
            worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
    }
}
```

For the web response the classic way:

```
var excelStream = GetExcelByteStream("MyExcelFilename");
context.Response.Clear(); 
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment;filename="+context.Request.Form["txtFileName"].ToString()); 
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", excelStream.Length.ToString()); 
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
context.Response.BinaryWrite(excelStream);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an `.xls` or is an `.xlsx` acceptable as well?

I'm the author of [a simple .xlsx writer](https://github.com/mstum/simplexcel) library for C# which supports writing to a stream without going through a file.

[The documentation](http://mstum.github.io/Simplexcel/#d5e58) contains an example ASP.net MVC ActionResult - you can inherit from it and then override the GenerateWorkbook method to generate the Workbook from your Database Tables.

```
public abstract class ExcelResultBase : ActionResult
{
private readonly string _filename;

protected ExcelResultBase(string filename)
{
    _filename = filename;
}

protected abstract Workbook GenerateWorkbook();

public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }

    var workbook = GenerateWorkbook();
    if (workbook == null)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return;
    }

    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    context.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + _filename + "\"");
    workbook.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
}
}
```

Comment: I can convert the list<objects> to byte[]. Can I use that byte[] anywhere here to create xls?

Comment: @Vishnu No, since you can't embed binary data into Excel. I assume the `List<object>` contains strings and ints and stuff? You basically have to look through every row from the database and then put every column value into a Cell within a Worksheet. I don't know NHibernate so I don't know what you actually get back from the database. Normally you should get something better than a `List<object>`, something strongly typed? In any case, you have to manually loop through your data and create Excel `Cell`s from it.

Comment: I am getting a list of objects,with each object contains string,int etc. I want to convert that to a byte[]. Is there any way?